# AnyChart APEX5 Integration

Tags: javascript, xml, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, anychart

I'm developing a web page with APEX 5. I want to show an AnyChart of a type, which is not included in the APEX Chart Region options, e.g. area charts or marker charts. I've had multiple ideas, but couldn't make it work. Has anyone succeeded in showing custom AnyCharts in APEX pages with the help of standard AnyChart JavaScript API or XML?

I tried with both XML and JavaScript, called from a Dynamic Action on Page Load. But I couldn't find the right configuration, it never worked. I would be glad if someone has an example of a functioning AnyChart integration, I'd like to know what to place where and when.

Answer (score 1):

We use custom AnyChart XML on most of our Diagrams.
But we use it with Application Proccesses.

HTML Code:

```
<span id="chartSpan"> </span>
```

The JS Code is as following:

For Adding the Element (change paths accordingly):

```
var chart = new AnyGantt('/i422/flashchart/anygantt_4/swf/AnyGantt.swf');

chart.addEventListener('resourceSelect', onResourceSelect);
chart.addEventListener('periodSelect', onPeriodSelect);
chart.addEventListener('periodEditingEnd', onPeriodEdit);

chart.width = "100%";
chart.height = "70%";
chart.write("chartSpan");
```

For loading the Data:

```
apex.server.process ("GEN_XML_AJAXDATA_PROJECT", {
  pageItems: "#P28_PROJECTID",
    x01: $v('P28_PROJECTID'),
    x02: 'another parameter',
  }, {
    dataType: "text"
  , success: function( pData ) { 
  xmlData = pData;
  //flash = AnyGantt._charts.chart__0;      
  flash = chart;

  flash.setXMLDataFromString(xmlData);
// do something 

} );
```

The Application process "GEN_XML_AJAXDATA_PROJECT" (shortend):

```
declare
l_data clob;
l_chart_data_xml varchar2(32767);

l_amt integer := 4000;
l_pos integer := 1;
l_buf varchar2(32000);


begin

sys.htp.htbuf_len := 63;

dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_data, FALSE, dbms_lob.session );
dbms_lob.open(l_data, dbms_lob.lob_readwrite );


--add your xml data code here
l_chart_data_xml := '<anygantt>  <settings>
<navigation enabled="True" position="Top" size="30"> 
</navigation>
<editing allow_edit="true">
  <rounding>
    <date unit="Week" step="1" />
  </rounding>
</editing>';
dbms_lob.writeappend(l_data, length(l_chart_data_xml), l_chart_data_xml);

IF apex_application.g_x02 = 'false' THEN 
End;
    for resrow in (SELECT apex_application.g_x01 AS CSVLINE FROM DUAL) loop
    l_chart_data_xml := resrow.CSVLINE||chr(13)||chr(10);
end loop;

l_chart_data_xml := '</resource_chart>' || chr(10) || '</anygantt>';
dbms_lob.writeappend(l_data, length(l_chart_data_xml), l_chart_data_xml);


loop
    begin
        dbms_lob.read(l_data, l_amt, l_pos, l_buf );
        l_pos := l_pos + l_amt;
        l_amt := 4000;

        sys.htp.prn( l_buf );

        exception
        when no_data_found then
            exit;
    end;
end loop;


dbms_lob.close(l_data);
if l_data is not null then
    dbms_lob.freetemporary(l_data);
end if;

end;
```

I highly advise using chrome developer options to debug your ajax response. With that you figure your problems in notime:
[image: Chrome Developer OPtions]

Comment: thank you very much. I'm going to take a look at it and try to adjust it to my needs. Will get back to ya.